# Selecting all for the week xx, not working properly php

Tags: php, date, mktime

Ok this is what i have:

```
function getFirstDayOfWeek($iYear, $iWeekNumber)
{
    if ( is_null($iYear) ) $iYear = date('Y');
    if ( $iWeekNumber < 10 ) $iWeekNumber = '0'.$iWeekNumber;

    $iTime = strtotime($iYear.'W'.$iWeekNumber);

    return $iTime;
}

$firstdayofweek = getFirstDayOfWeek($data['year'], $data['week']);
$mDate = date('m', $firstdayofweek);
$dDate = date('d', $firstdayofweek);
$min = mktime(0, 0, 0, $mDate, $dDate, $data['year']);
$max = mktime(23, 59, 59, $dDate, $dDate+6, $data['year']);
```

Where it later does:

```
SELECT id
FROM training_activities
WHERE date time >= {$min} 
  AND time <= {$max}
```

As you may now until now, the times are saved in unix timestamp.

This code is not working properly.

Lets say $data year is 2011 and week 39.

This shows me dates from 26/09-04/10, 8 days, while the week 39 is 29/09 - 02/10

How can i make it select and show weeks right?

Comment: Your `$min`/`$max` variable declarations are very hard to understand. Please use a variable for some/all of the inline function calls (`date()`, `getFirstDayOfWeek()`).

Comment: @JaredFarrish ok what about now?

Comment: Well, that's better. `:)` Now your query doesn't look right: `SELECT id
FROM training_activities
WHERE date time >= {$min} 
  AND time <= {$max}
` Is it `date time` or `time`? The first doesn't look right.

Comment: Please clearly state what you are trying to do, as it is not clearly inferred from the question.

Comment: And here is just the PHP code tested: http://codepad.org/arUMxn4n (of which I don't see any problem). Is the database returning the faulty values?

Comment: I want to select everything within a week you have chosen. E.g if you want to display everything within 39, it should select everything from 26/09 - 02/10 (but this needs to be in unix timestamp)

Comment: @JaredFarrish I just tried that, with a week, 39, see: http://codepad.org/acUumWQv that is wrong.. ?

Comment: @JaredFarrish Ok you have placed it like m/d/Y, see your codepad: 09/26/2011 - 03/04/2013 that is wrong? It should be 09/26/2011 - 10/02/2011 ?

Comment: Your PHP code doesn't seem to be returning incorrect values (see my codepad link in my comment above, this year the first Monday was January 3rd, the next Sunday was the 9th). I also don't see a problem with the 39th week. I would investigate the query you're generating.

Comment: It's not about removing saturday and sunday, i do want them. But week 39 can't be 09/26/2011 - 03/04/2013 <- even year is wrong?! 
And week 39 is 09/26/2011 - 10/02/2011, see http://www.epochconverter.com/date-and-time/weeknumbers-by-year.php :P

Comment: Ok, nevermind. You were using `$dDate` in the `$max` when you needed to use `$mDate`: http://codepad.org/Mo6ch0MW (This only shows Monday-Friday, change the `+4` back to `+6` for the weekend.)

Comment: Sorry, i wasn't looking at it closely enough. This will give you the whole week: http://codepad.org/7hMJQFhq

Comment: Great!! Please post it as an answer

Comment: Sorry about that; I was focusing on the day only because of your comment in the question about 8 days but was neglecting to look at the month and year. `:S`

Comment: Note, you might want to put that into a function like `getWeekUnixtime()` and return an `array($start,$end)`. Then you could just call that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$max` month was using `$dDate` instead of `$mDate`; the following works:

```
<?php

function getFirstDayOfWeek($iYear, $iWeekNumber)
{
    if ( is_null($iYear) ) $iYear = date('Y');
    if ( $iWeekNumber < 10 ) $iWeekNumber = '0'.$iWeekNumber;

    $iTime = strtotime($iYear.'W'.$iWeekNumber);

    return $iTime;
}

for ($i = 1; $i <= 52; $i++) {
    $firstdayofweek = getFirstDayOfWeek(2011, $i);
    $mDate = date('m', $firstdayofweek);
    $dDate = date('d', $firstdayofweek);
    $min = mktime(0, 0, 0, $mDate, $dDate, 2011);
    $max = mktime(23, 59, 59, $mDate, ($dDate+6), 2011);
    echo date('m/d/Y',$min)." - ".date('m/d/Y',$max)." ($dDate - ".($dDate+6).")\n";
}

?>
```

http://codepad.org/7hMJQFhq